# How do I use Intent to get a list of files on the Android device

Tags: android, android-intent

Here's the code so far

```
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            intent.SetType("file/*.txt");
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
           
        }
```

And that works to an extent. When I click on the button (which activates this code) I get a rather blank screen with Select Item, Internal Storage, One Drive, Google Drive, but selecting Internal storage doesn't do anything. How can I see a list of files?

Thank you.